# Why cannot import library from go get?

Tags: go, redis, go-get

I downloaded go-redis client using

```
go mod init github.com/my/repo
go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v8
```

But it showed [cannot find package "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/trace"](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/issues/1534). So I deleted go-redis from ${GOPATH}/src/github.com and then tried running it again

```
go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v8
```

But it does nothing. Doesn't show any error or any message. But when I try to import package it says

> cannot find package "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8" in any of:
>  /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 (from $GOROOT)
>  /home/username/go/src/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 (from $GOPATH)

I tried `go mod tidy` `go mod clean` but none worked. What should I do?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/go-redis/redis/issues/1534 This might help!

Comment: I had the same problem, try to remove go.sum, type ``go mid tidy`` and try using golang 14.0>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ls `$GOPATH` , if is not showing your path of golang library source, you should set path first,
2. If point 1 is able, you should just doing :`go mod tidy`

tidy argument make you doing download package with sync method, without doing go get separately.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use go vendoring, it will add your dependencies to vendor/ and -mod=vendor will tell golang to search for dependencies locally.

1. Remove go.sum
2. Type `export GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor`
3. Type `go mod tidy && go mod vendor`

If you can't export variables, use go run and go build with the prefix `GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor`, for example `GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor go run cmd/main/main.go`

Don't forget to add vendor/ to your .gitignore

Comment: GO MOD VENDOR!!! Hit SO many posts trying to remember this command and finally someone said it!! Thanks man :)